# How to split records evenly into 4 tables from one table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, rowcount

I have to design a solution that will help me out to load data into 4 tables from 1 master table.

All that the function or package is supposed to do is following :

- Count total number of rows in a master table
- Divide by 4
- Load into table 1,2,3 and 4.

Every time we run the program, this function wipes out 4 tables and do the above process again and the name of the main table and of the destination tables will be always same.

For example, if the Master Table has 4200 records then :

- Table A will get 1-1000
- Table B will get 1001-2000
- Table C will get 2001-3000
- Table D will get 3001-4200.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to tag *only* the sql engine you're using. I doubt this is on both mysql and sql-server

Comment: make use of `row_number()`

Comment: Does this table contains an identity field?

Comment: Yes, the column name itself is "Primary Key".

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple way to do it. There may be faster ways. Replace [TABLE] with the name of your table and [ID] with the name of a unique column in the table.

```
DECLARE @count int = 0;
DECLARE @numRecsPerTable int = 0;

SELECT @count = COUNT(*) FROM [TABLE]
SELECT @numRecsPerTable = @count / 4

SELECT TOP (@numRecsPerTable) * 
INTO temp_1
FROM [TABLE]

SELECT TOP (@numRecsPerTable) * 
INTO temp_2
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE [ID] NOT IN (SELECT TOP (@numRecsPerTable) [ID] FROM [TABLE])

SELECT TOP (@numRecsPerTable) * 
INTO temp_3
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE [ID] NOT IN (SELECT TOP (@numRecsPerTable * 2) [ID] FROM [TABLE])

SELECT * 
INTO temp_4
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE [ID] NOT IN (SELECT TOP (@numRecsPerTable * 3) [ID] FROM [TABLE])
```

Note: the remainder of recs / 4 will be in the 4th table.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for this very effective solution. Now trying to put in some form of ssis package or procuder

Answer (score 0):

The SSIS implementation is similar to Steve's answer.

[image]

### Source

The first difference is that instead of division, we'll use the modulo operator, `%` It generates the remainder after division. In this example, I use `%4` which means I will have values of 0, 1, 2 and 3. Four "buckets" of data. To give the modulus operator something to work on, I use the `ROW_NUMBER` function to generate an arbitrary monotonically incrementing sequence of numbers.

The query would look something like

```
SELECT
    T.* 
,   (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))) % 4 AS bucketNumber 
FROM 
    sys.all_columns AS T;
```

### Conditional Split

I route the data to a Conditional Split component. Here you define boolean expressions and correlate them to named outputs. I defined mine as Bucket0, Bucket1, Bucket2, Bucket3 and used expressions of `bucketNumber==0`...

### Destination

I now have 4 connectors coming out of my conditional split and wire them up to tables Bucket0 to Bucket3.